# "There are better ways to describe semantics than Java bytecodes"?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

Cliff Click, in his speech, "A JVM Does That?", says "There are better ways to describe semantics than Java bytecodes": http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uL2D3qzHtqY&t=8m55s

Why? What are the problems with Java bytecode? What are the alternatives?

Comment: This question appears to be more appropriate for Programmers Exchange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bytecode already loses quite a lot of semantics, that's the problem. It is a kind of unstructured machine code. As a case in point, witness the enormous complexity of a Java decompiler: it's basically the C.S.I. team of Java, painstakingly reconstructing the source code from the fragments of information dispersed around the bytecode.

Since modern JVMs don't have much use for the bytecode except as a description of program semantics, it has lost its original purpose, which was to be a relatively fast-to-interpret format, intermediate in the level of description between Java and native machine code.

The JIT compiler will actually have a *harder* time optimizing bytecode well than it would have had with the original source code, because it wants to know as much as possible about the intent behind a piece of code. Consider this piece of code:

```
int i = 0;
String s = "";
for (Integer num : nums) { 
  s += num;
  if (++i < ints.size()) s += ", ";
}
```

What does the code do? After some analysis and confirming a few conjectures, it turns out that it assembles a comma-separated string from a list of integers. There are a lot of things to optimize, though:

1. using the immutable `String` type to hold interim values through the loop;
2. maintaining a separate index variable, `i`, which is a duplicate of the one held within the implicit `Iterator`;
3. checking `i` against the list size each time even though it is clear this will be true only on the last iteration.

The JIT compiler will routinely perform a *loop specialization* optimization: it will emit separate code just for the last loop step, thereby completely eliminating the repeated `if` check. It may also realize that the interim strings are not escaping and automatically replace the whole idiom with a `StringBuilder`-based one.

For all this to happen, it is clear that the compiler must attain a quite thorough high-level understanding of what is going on, something that would be much easier to achieve with the source code than the resulting bytecode.

The modern trend in programming languages is to distribute the source code itself as the entry point for the JIT, or something very similar to the source code, like the AST.

Comment: This sounds very interesting. Is this trend you described in the end of your answer being done in any "mainstream" language implementation? By mainstream java, c#, php, python, ruby, javascript, or any of those popular languages of "today". And, any description on the results they're getting?

Comment: Abosolutely---all dynamic languages are distributed by source code (php, python, ruby, javascript). The runtime usually performs a shallow "compilation" of the source code (basically turns it into a binary form of the same thing) and starts optimizing from that. As for the results, nobody is as far ahead as HotSpot and derivatives, but you surely know the tales of V8 and other modern optimizing runtimes.

Comment: By looking at what decompilers can do when the byte code not has been obfuscated, there is not much information lost. The names of local variables and whether a loop was a `for` or a `while` loop and other things irrelevant to the execution. There are two questionable claims in this answer. First, that source code really tells (more) about the semantic of a program. Second, that knowing something about the semantic was useful for optimizing the code. But that never was the question. Java bytecode indeed doesn’t tell much about the semantic. But that never was the intent of programming.

Answer (score 2):

From a quick scan (not a full listen) of the talk, it seems to be about the ways that Java hides details from the user, and ideas for other details it could hide and/or ways an operating system could better help it.

In that context: He's talking about the fact that the abstract definition of Java is that the bytecodes are interpreted -- and interpreting bytecodes is a very slow process. But "under the covers", Java uses the JIT compiler -- and in hotspot JITs, uses performance profiling to perform some more sophisticated optimizations -- to "create the illusion" that bytecodes are running quickly.

If you're developing the next generation of Java environments, operating systems, or languages these distinctions matter.

But as far as most folks are concerned, that's no more meaningful than the fact that modern processors overlap the execution of some instructions. Most folks don't think about bytecodes at all beyond knowing that they're a portable representation of code. They compile Java. They load it into their JVM. It runs at a reasonable speed. Done.